# Regex replace non alphanumeric that are adjacent to white-spaces in C#

Tags: regex, string

I want to replace all non-alphanumeric in a string that are adjacent to at-least one white-space character.

For example: result for "**Replace (all non-alphanumeric from - this -string-** " should be "**Replace all non-alphanumeric from this string**".

What will be the correct regex to do this?

The best i have so far is this: `@"[^a-zA-Z0-9]\s+[\s+^a-zA-Z0-9]"` but it's not working

Comment: Try [`Regex.Replace(s, @"(\s)+[^\w\s]+\s*|(\s)*[^\w\s]+\s+", "$1$2")`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5cs%29%2b%5b%5e%5cw%5cs%5d%2b%5cs*%7c%28%5cs%29*%5b%5e%5cw%5cs%5d%2b%5cs%2b&i=Replace+%28++++all+non-alphanumeric+from+-+this+-string-+&r=%241%242)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex matches the space as well, and it also requires non-alphanumeric symbols on *both* sides of space.

Change this to an OR-ed expression that combines a non-alphanumeric preceded by a space, and a non-alphanumeric followed by a space:

```
@"[^a-zA-Z0-9](?=\s)|(?<=\s)[^a-zA-Z0-9]"
```

Lookahead and lookbehind [constructs `(?=...)` and `(?<=\s)`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) are non-capturing, so the spaces are going to remain in place.

Comment: The `[\s+^a-zA-Z0-9]` matches alphanumeric chars, whitespace, `^` and `+`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Oops, I copy-pasted a wrong part of OP's expression. Thanks!

Comment: Anyway, even `[^a-zA-Z0-9](?=\s)|(?<=\s)[^a-zA-Z0-9]` will leave consecutive spaces in the string, it will need post-processing.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I though OP wants to keep all spaces, consecutive or not, although the example shows a single space between `from` and `this`.

Comment: Thanks @dasblinkenlight. Even i have a similar one now.               
     @"\s[^a-zA-Z0-9]|[^a-zA-Z0-9]\s"

Comment: @suri This one needs to be replaced with space, because it matches space `\s` as well.

Comment: I was actually doing that (**regex.Replace(strToProcess, " ")**). That's why i didn't  go for the complexity of look-ahead and look-behind.